OIDC logout using Okta has been blocked by CORS policy
I have configured Okta as my OpenId Connect provider. I am able to successfully login into my local application using okta but when i try to logout. My logout request gets blocked with this error "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I am using Spring OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler onLogoutSucess method to initiate a okta logout request. I have configured post_logout_redirect_uri to some random site ex. https://www.google.com.
Things i have checked

I have added my localhost domain in okta Sigout Uri.
I have also added localhost domain in okta CORS trusted origin.

But still its not working.
Error I am getting.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-02249888.okta.com/oauth2/v1/logout?id_token_hint=actual_id_token&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'http://platform.test.com/testcontext/api/login/logout') from origin 'http://platform.test.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is your frontend a single-page application (Angular, React, Vue,...)?

your request is coming not from localhost but from http://platform.test.com, that's what should be enabled in CORS

RP-Initiated Logout doesn't have to use cross-origin requests.
Suppose you initiate the logout with plain navigation instead of sending a POST request with a programmatic client. In that case, the response with the redirection to the authorization server will be plain navigation too.
For that, use the HTML form tag with action and method attributes:
<form action="/logout" method="post">
  <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>

But this should fail because of CSRF protection. As a reminder, protection against CSRF should always be enabled in a filter chain with oauth2Login because of security based on session cookies.
If the application is rendered on the server (with Thymeleaf or alike), it might be possible to add the CSRF token to the form as a hidden input (not really sure about that, I don't use Thymeleaf in prod).
But if your frontend is a single-page application, your backend likely expects the CSRF token as an X-XSRF-TOKEN header, which you can't set with a plain HTML form. The solution with an ajax request I detailed in this Baeldung article is as follows:

send a POST request to logout with the SPA HTTP client (that's an ajax request, not a plain navigation)
modify the status of the response from the Spring client with oauth2Login to be in the 2xx range (instead of 302)
in the SPA code, read the Location header of this response and follow by setting windows.location.href, which exits the app and starts a new navigation

So instead of the <form> above:
<button (click)="logout()">logout</button>

logout() {
  this.http
    .post('/logout', null, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => this.user$.next(User.ANONYMOUS))
    )
    .subscribe((resp) => {
      // warning, we can't "observe" a response with 302 status
      const logoutUri = resp.headers.get('Location');
      if (!!logoutUri) {
        // this starts a new navigation
        window.location.href = logoutUri;
      }
    });
}

Note that Angular auto-magically sets the X-XSRF-TOKEN header when the server sets an XSRF-TOKEN cookie. If using another framework, it might be necessary to set that header manually.
